# SQL Server query that allows me to show an overview of books within bookcases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get my program to show an overview of all the bookcases in my database with the associated bookshelves / compartments and the books within those shelves or compartments.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 windows forms application.

My SQL Server database structure is as follows :

- `user` table (userId, username, password)
- `bookcase` table (bookcaseId, name, location, userId)
- `Shelf` table (shelfId, bookcaseId)
- `compartment` table (compartmentId, bookcaseId)
- `book` table (bookid, title, author, serie, genre, compartmentId, shelfId)

I know how to use a query to get an overview for all books, shelves, users etc by using `Select *` from each table.

I also know that to order I simply use `Order by bookcaseId`.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: And what does "overview" mean?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach is to use `bookshelves` for your `FROM` clause. The reason for this approach (if I understand your database design correctly) is the fact, that `bookcaseId` seems to be a foreign key in `shelf` and `compartment` tables.

```
SELECT 
    bk.bookcaseId, bk.name, bk.location,
    b.bookid, b.title, b.author, b.serie, b.genre, b.compartmentId, b.shelfId
FROM bookcase bk
LEFT JOIN shelf s ON (bk.bookcaseId = s.bookcaseId)
LEFT JOIN compartment c ON (bk.bookcaseId = c.bookcaseId)
LEFT JOIN book b ON (c.compartmentId = b.compartmentId) AND (s.shelfId = b.shelfId)
ORDER BY bk.bookcaseId, s.shelfId, c.compartmentId
```

Comment: Yes , this was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can join them on the correct keys.
Then get the fields you need from them.

That bookcaseId is a foreign key in 2 of the tables.

So it might be that either compartmentId or/and shelfId is populated in the books table.

But you can join on both and then also get the user for both.

```
SELECT 
book.title AS book_title, 
book.author AS book_author, 
book.serie AS book_serie,
book.genre AS book_genre,
bcs.name AS shelf_bookcase_name, 
bcs.location AS shelf_bookcase_location,
us.username AS shelf_bc_username,
bcc.name AS compartment_bookcase_name, 
bcc.location AS compartment_bookcase_location,
uc.username AS compartment_bc_username
FROM book
LEFT JOIN compartment AS cmp ON cmp.compartmentId = book.compartmentId
LEFT JOIN bookcase AS bcc ON bcc.bookcaseId = cmp.bookcaseId
LEFT JOIN [user] AS uc ON uc.userId = bcc.userId
LEFT JOIN shelf ON shelf.shelfId = book.shelfId
LEFT JOIN bookcase AS bcs ON bcs.bookcaseId = shelf.bookcaseId
LEFT JOIN [user] AS us ON us.userId = bcs.userId
ORDER BY coalesce(shelf.bookcaseId, cmp.bookcaseId)
```